# Array of Array in C++/CLI or managed C++

Tags: c++-cli

How can we translate this C# code:

```
Mesh m7 = new Mesh();

m7.MakeFace(new ICurve[] {(ICurve) redLp }, 
            new ICurve[][] { new ICurve[] { circle } }, Plane.XY, tol, true);
```

To Managed C++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
array<ICurve^>^ ar1 = gcnew array<ICurve^> { redLp };
array<array<ICurve^>^>^ ar2 = gcnew array<array<ICurve^>^>{
  gcnew array<ICurve^> { circle }
  }; 

IList<ICurve^>^ list1 = gcnew List<ICurve^>(ar1);
IList<IList<ICurve^>^>^ list2 = gcnew List<IList<ICurve^>^>();
list2->Add( gcnew List<ICurve^>(ar2[0]) );

Mesh^ m7 = gcnew Mesh();
m7->MakeFace( list1, list2, Plane::XY, tol, true);
```

Note: it might be possible that `Plane::XY` should be `Plane.XY`, or `Plane->XY` but i assumed an Enum.

Comment: @ngoozeff: I get the following error when I compile the Visual Studio project: error C2664: 'void Mesh::MakeFace(System::Collections::Generic::IList<T> ^,System::Collections::Generic::IList<System::Collections::Generic::IList<T> ^> ^,devDept::Geometry::Plane ^,double,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'System::Collections::Generic::IList<T> ^'

Comment: @ngoozeff: Now this is the compilation error: "error C2872: 'IList' : ambiguous symbol" at the following line: IList<ICurve^>^ list1 = gcnew List<ICurve^>(ar1);

Comment: @devdept: you might have both "using namespace System::Collections::Generic;" and "using namespace System::Collections;" at the top of your cpp. If you look in the Output window, it should say what is causing the ambiguity.

Comment: @ngoozeff: using both:
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
but the error is always the C2872 reported above... Thanks for the help provided so far.

Comment: @devdept: sorry, should have been more clear. You should only have the Generic namespace.

Comment: @ngoozeff: Nothing changes, sorry.

Comment: I am having the same problem with IList, List works fine though.